# Display row as column

Tags: php, html

The following code is displaying product name in one row and quantity,price and subtotal in new row, how to get all these on same row. Output screenshot as been attached below.

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX0bA.jpg)

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $r = 1;
            $tax_summary = array();
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                if (isset($tax_summary[$row->tax_code])) {
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['items'] += $row->quantity;
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['tax'] += $row->item_tax;
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['amt'] += ($row->quantity * $row->net_unit_price) - $row->item_discount;
                } else {
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['items'] = $row->quantity;
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['tax'] = $row->item_tax;
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['amt'] = ($row->quantity * $row->net_unit_price) - $row->item_discount;
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['name'] = $row->tax_name;
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['code'] = $row->tax_code;
                    $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['rate'] = $row->tax_rate;
                }
                echo '<tr><td colspan="2">#' . $r . ': &nbsp;&nbsp;' . product_name($row->product_name) . ($row->variant ? ' (' . $row->variant . ')' : '') . '<span class="pull-right">' . $row->tax_code . '</span></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>' . $this->sma->formatNumber($row->quantity) . ' x ';

                if ($row->item_discount != 0) {
                    echo '<del>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($row->net_unit_price + ($row->item_discount / $row->quantity) + ($row->item_tax / $row->quantity)) . '</del> ';
                }

                echo $this->sma->formatMoney($row->net_unit_price + ($row->item_tax / $row->quantity)) . '</td><td class="text-right">' . $this->sma->formatMoney($row->subtotal) . '</td></tr>';
                $r++;
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change anything in this code?

Comment: tried changing rows to columns but no change

Answer (score 0):

Try below, but probabbly the formatting will be broken:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<tbody>
<?php
$r = 1;
$tax_summary = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (isset($tax_summary[$row->tax_code])) {
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['items'] += $row->quantity;
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['tax'] += $row->item_tax;
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['amt'] += ($row->quantity * $row->net_unit_price) - $row->item_discount;
    } else {
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['items'] = $row->quantity;
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['tax'] = $row->item_tax;
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['amt'] = ($row->quantity * $row->net_unit_price) - $row->item_discount;
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['name'] = $row->tax_name;
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['code'] = $row->tax_code;
        $tax_summary[$row->tax_code]['rate'] = $row->tax_rate;
    }
    echo '<tr><td colspan="2">#' . $r . ': &nbsp;&nbsp;' . product_name($row->product_name) . ($row->variant ? ' (' . $row->variant . ')' : '') . '<span class="pull-right">' . $row->tax_code . '</span>';
    echo '' . $this->sma->formatNumber($row->quantity) . ' x ';

    if ($row->item_discount != 0) {
        echo '<del>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($row->net_unit_price + ($row->item_discount / $row->quantity) + ($row->item_tax / $row->quantity)) . '</del> ';
    }

    echo $this->sma->formatMoney($row->net_unit_price + ($row->item_tax / $row->quantity)) . '' . $this->sma->formatMoney($row->subtotal) . '</td></tr>';
    $r++;
}
?>
</tbody>
```